# DOCKER: error when running gulp-php website

Tags: php, docker, gulp

I am trying to use Docker in order to run my php - gulp website.
Here is the tree of what I've created:

```
├── app <--------------------contains the php files
├── blog-theme
├── bower_components
├── changelog-YYYY-MM-DD.md
├── dist
├── Dockerfile <-----------------------DOCKERFILE
├── get-git-log.sh
├── git-log.txt
├── gulpfile.js <------------------all my gulp tasks are here 
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── Releases
├── ressources
├── website_test.sh
└── yarn.lock
```

The app folder contains all my php files:

```
app
├── folder1
│   └── index.php
├── folder2
│   └── index.php
├── folder3
│   └── index.php
├── footer.php
├── header.php
└── index.php
```

My gulpfile.js contains all the tasks to compile and build my website. It is working well. The command I use to run is `gulp build-production && gulp serve:dist` due to the name of the tasks I've created.

So in my Dockerfile, I added the following lines in order to make my app running in my Docker:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm install -g n
RUN n 13.6.0
RUN npm i gulp@4.0.2
RUN npm i gulp-cli

VOLUME ["/app"]
CMD ["gulp build-production && gulp serve:dist"]
```

When I am running `docker build -t myapp .` all the steps are working well without returning any error.

But then when I run `docker run myapp` I got the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"gulp build-production && gulp serve:dist\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I am very confused so if anyone has a solution it would be awesome.

Comment: Remove the brackets and quotes around the `CMD` line.  I'd also recommend deleting the `VOLUME` line, and more directly installing Node (maybe even just use the Ubuntu `nodejs` package).

Comment: David gave nice suggestions, And sorry, it's not part of question, but think for the sake of following good practices. You can reduce your image file size by consolidate multiple commands into a single `RUN`, to something like `RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y curl`

Comment: When I am removing the brackets and the quotes around the CMD line, when running ```docker run myapp``` it returns the following issue: ```/bin/sh: 1: gulp: not found```

Comment: @CamilleBOUQUET try adding line `RUN npm i gulp in dockerfile and rebuild image and test or RUN npm install -g gulp
RUN npm link gulp
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use node image instead of ubuntu, because with this you do not need to reinstall it later.

I think your main problem is that you should create app directory first and copy all your website content.

Then you can also remove `VOLUME` this is useless in your case.

Something you can try:

```
FROM node:14

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y php
RUN npm install -g n
RUN n 13.6.0
RUN npm i -g gulp-cli
RUN npm install

ENV PATH=$PATH:/app/node_modules/.bin
ENTRYPOINT [] # to bypass default node
CMD gulp serve:dist
```

Answer (score 0):

`/app/node_modules/.bin/` is not in your `$PATH`.
Either add it with `ENV PATH=$PATH:/app/node_modules/.bin` or prefix gulp with the path `CMD ["/app/node_modules/.bin/gulp build-production && /app/node_modules/.bin/gulp serve:dist"]`.